# How do I add a parameter to a method in my interface in C# without breaking clients?

Tags: c#, interface

I wrote a public interface in my C# application that has the following method:

```
IMimic OpenMimic(string mimicPath, string frameModel, string branch, int regionId);
```

I also wrote an abstract base class that implements this interface, and at the same time, I wrote a public sealed class that implements this base class.

Now, I need to add a parameter to this method like this:

```
IMimic OpenMimic(string mimicPath, string frameModel, string branch, int regionId, IAlsContext mimicContext);
```

This implies I need to make changes to my base class and also my sealed implementation.

Right now, there are client applications (written by other teams in my organization) that use this class and call the old version of this method. If I change this method, I'm forced to change the interface as well.

Won't this break the clients? Is this an example of a typical breaking change? How can I fix it so that clients don't break? The problem is that this new parameter is a required parameter and I'm not an expert in interface programming.

Thanks,

Comment: One way for this is to solve is to have extension method for the interface which will use existing method of interface with extra code related to the new parameter. Have this is method created and release new version of your library. Clients won't break but they need to change their code eventually to take advantage of new method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Won't this break the clients?

Yep.

> Is this an example of a typical breaking change?

Yep.

> How can I fix it so that clients don't break?

You never, ever, ever change a public interface that a client depends on.

Write a new interface -- possibly one that extends the old interface -- and with a new method that has the right signature.

Then implement your classes to implement the new *and the old* interface. You might have to use an *explicit interface method* to do so.

The clients keep on working; they can choose to move to the new interface on their schedule.

You might also consider marking the old interface as "obsolete" in the *next* version, and then remove it the version *after* that.

> The problem is that this new parameter is a required parameter and I'm not an expert in interface programming.

Well, now you know more about interface programming than you did yesterday!

Comment: But in my particular case, I need to force the clients to move to the new interface since this is a required parameter. Client developers work in my organization, so I can let them know about the breaking change. Isn't this an exception to the rule in my case? When they see it won't compile they will be forced to provide the parameter on their next version. Again I stress that this is internal to our organization.

Comment: Eric explained how to avoid breaking changes, but it is not true that you have to avoid them. As long as you and your clients agree on this change, it is up to you how you handle this change.

Comment: @Ray: Your question was "how do I do this **without breaking clients**. Now you are saying that it is perfectly acceptable for you to break your clients and that you want to do so.  If you have a negotiation to do with clients in your organization about how to roll out a breaking change to them, that's not a question about *code*. That's a question about the political and management structure of your organization. I can't help you with that. **What question are you actually asking here, because it sounds like you are not sure.**

Comment: Ok, I understand a little better now. My question is correct. Eric answered my question. It's because I wasn't sure if I had to announce this as a Breaking Change to the clients or not. I wasn't sure if this is considered one, but now I know the answer is yes.

Comment: @Ray: Well, one way to announce breaking changes to clients is by using [Semantic Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/semantic-versioning/info).